# Phaser.js - how do I take an object out of a group?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm playing around with phasers invaders example game.

When the object is shot, instead of killing it I'm changing the sprite and moving it to the bottom of the screen. However, it can now be shot again. I don't want it to be shootable a 2nd time. I'm thinking that because the gamephysics are on the group 'aliens', there are probably two options.

a) Either I can take the single shot alien out of the group 'aliens' and hope that stops it from being shot a 2nd time.

b) Or there's some way of saying ' alien just shot = now protected from being shot again' ,  I tried the following to no avail.

```
alien.physicsBodyType = null;
```

This is my collision handler right now
    function collisionHandler (bullet, alien) {

```
//  When a bullet hits an alien we kill them both
bullet.kill();
alien.loadTexture("cured");
// move alien to bottom

var tween2 = game.add.tween(alien).to( { y: 300 }, 1000,    Phaser.Easing.Linear.EaseIn, true);
tween2.onComplete.add(doNext, this);
    tween2.start();
```

So, basically the changed sprite can still be shot at, I need to make it so it cannot be shot at.

I tried this.

```
game.world.add(happy);
```

It changed the position of the sprite and it was still shootable. Hmmm...

Is there a way to take collision off the single shot alien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my answer, just deactivate the body of the sprite, you don't need to take it out of the group.

```
sprite.body.enable = false;
```

Where 'sprite' is the name of your actual sprite. Tested and works.